# Undefined columns selected in R

Tags: r

I have a problem with data selection. For my analysis I just want to use 196 variables of over 700.

```
names(df)
proteins <- names(df[2:197]) 
df.log <- df [,proteins]
```

But I got this in return: Error in `[.data.frame(df, , proteins) : 
  undefined columns selected`

I'm wondering if there is a problem with the names of my variables. Because when I select other variables then it works without any problem. Here for example some Variables which don't work:

```
[1] "1-(O-alpha-D-glucopyranosyl)-29-keto-(1,3R,31R)-dotriacontanetriol"                                  
[2] "30-(-2-(O-2-hydroxy-ethane)-3-hydroxy-propane)-hopane"                                               
[3] "4-Amino-7-chloroquinoline"
```

These are actually working:

```
[1] "t1_part"
[2] "t1-bmi"
```

...

Any suggestions?

Greetings from germany

Comment: Try out `df.log  <- proteins[, 2:197]`

Comment: df.log <- df [,proteins]  - removing the coma should work too: df.log <- df[proteins]

Comment: df.log <- proteins[, 2:197] works. Thank you @ANG. I really don't get it why my approach didn't worked. But okay ..

Answer (score 0):

Use  `names(df)[2:197]` instead of `names(df[2:197])` it works with any kind of column names.

Check the following code for a dummy dataframe `df` with 700 columns having names *4-Amino-7-chloroquinoline* suffixed by number:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:2100,nrow = 3,ncol = 700))
names(df) <- paste("4-Amino-7-chloroquinoline",1:700, sep="_")
proteins <- names(df)[2:197]
df.log <- df [,proteins]
```

Hope this was helpful